# Where to start with native app using Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, flutter

I am looking to build an app where registered users can fill out a form (with some fields already prefilled for different forms) and then submit the form.

Users will need to be authenticated on the app. I'm thinking that Firebase might be best suited for the data, but not sure where to start as for the actual development and am looking for some advice. Do I use Flutter, React or another?

Is there any examples where anyone could point me to?

Thanks

Comment: Your question contains some subquestions.
Firstly, Flutter and React-Native is for cross-platform solutions, not Native one, but the performance of Flutter is just amazing, you will be surprised if you tried any other technologies for cross-platform development before.

Another thing, yes, you can use Firebase Authentication module/lib, it exists for both solutions you mentioned in your question and you could detect your users by their unique ID from the smartphone.

Comment: Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

[oficial firebase/flutter exercise](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) this is a light begin in configuring firebase in flutter.
After checking it you can take a look at this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth), inside of the github repo the plugin author got some nice [examples](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/example)